# How to interpret JQuery UI's API documentation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to interpret the JQuery UI API documentation?

For example they write documentation like this

```
Bind to the start event by type: selectablestart.

$( ".selector" ).bind( "selectablestart", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

How do I know what methods I can invoke on `ui`?

Comment: Good question - all the other interaction components seem to detail their `ui` object in the Overview section of the docs ([e.g for Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)), but Selectable doesn't. Have you tried inspecting the `ui` argument in a console?

Comment: Thanks good suggestion with the inspection. That's what I normally do, but I wanted to get a faster way of parsing JQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the first page of a jQuery UI method "Overview" tells you what properties the `ui` object gives. In the case of selectable though this is missing because there is no second argument. There simply isn't anything useful to pass to the user.

Comment: Is this mentioned somewhere on the webpage or is it just from experience/inspection?

Comment: You can have a look in the source, it simply doesn't do anything with `ui`. Alternatively you could run `$('#selectable').bind( "selectablestart", function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui)
}).trigger("selectablestart");` in the console and you will get nothing but another `this`.

Comment: I don't follow the answer the ui element has a property "selected" and I can use it they way I intender wiht ui.selected.innerHTML

Comment: can you recreate that in a fiddle? I get an empty object for `ui` when binding with the console on jQuery ui's demo page